# JavaFX TextField.getText() unexpected results

Tags: if-statement, javafx, textfield

I wrote this little piece of code in JavaFX:

```
tfb.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override public void handle (ActionEvent e) {
        if(tf1.getText() == "test") {
            System.out.println("correct");
        } else {
            System.out.println("wrong");
        }
    }
});
```

When I enter "test" in the text field, I always get a "wrong" printed by my code, not a "correct" as it should be. I checked several times whether I spelled "test" correctly, and I also tried to put "test" in quotation marks (double: `"` and single: `'`), none of this helped.

I already tried to print out the content of the text field (with `System.out.Println(tf1.getText())`), and I got what I wrote in the text field on the console, so the action listener and `tf1.getText()` work for sure.

What can be wrong with my code?

Comment: BTW: `'`-quotes are for chars only. The compiler only allows you to add exactly one char in between those.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try to replace the if with the following,

```
if(tf1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("test")){
     System.out.println("correct");
} else {
     System.out.println("wrong");
}
```

Comment: `TextField.getText` returns a string and the question does not indicate that case of letters should be ignored...

Comment: For string comparison you should use .equals or equalsIgnoreCase instead of '==',  better use equalsIgnoreCase if it is not case sensitive